# Combine multiple instances of same product ID that have multiple values for different foreign keys?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a product database in MySQL and am trying to view the content with PHP. I am currently working with 3 tables: prod, div, and prodCatDiv. The prod table holds the data for each product while the div table holds the IDs for each of my company's 5 divisions. The prodCatDiv table is a join table with foreign keys relating to the ID of the other two tables.

My tables are set up as such:

```
prod
-
prodID | prodName | prodImg | prodDesc

div
-
divID | divName

prodCatDiv
-
prodID | catID | divID
```

My SQL statement is as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM prod LEFT JOIN prodCatDiv ON prod.prodID=prodCatDiv.prodID ORDER BY prodUpdate DESC";
```

However, when I try to populate a page with the data from these tables, I get multiple listings from the same prodID. So, if I have prodID=1 attributed to both divID=1 and divID=2, it lists that product twice with the first and second division on each listing. How can I combine these two listings so that it shows one prodID=1 as being attributed to BOTH divID=1 AND divID=2?

I have a table on a page to display the results. In this table there are columns for each division that are "checkmarked" so that the user can see what divisions each product is in. Currently, it creates two rows for a product if that product is in two divisions. I want this product based on prodID to be a single row with a checkmark in both division columns it's attributed to.

Comment: Please show an example of what you want the results to look like?

Comment: I have a table on a page to display the results. In this table there are columns for each division that are "checkmarked" so that the user can see what divisions each product is in. Currently, it creates two rows for a product if that product is in two divisions. I want this product based on prodID to be a single row with a checkmark in both division columns it's attributed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the values and create a single column with the list of `DivId`s:

```
SELECT p.*, group_concat(pcd.DivId separator ', ') as DivIds
FROM prod p LEFT JOIN
     prodCatDiv pcd
     ON p.prodID = pcd.prodID
GROUP BY p.ProdId
ORDER BY prodUpdate DESC;
```